# Scala type inference question

Tags: scala, type-inference, catamorphism

I was just pottering about with [Tony Morris' excellent exercise on catamorphisms](http://blog.tmorris.net/debut-with-a-catamorphism/), when I was pondering what was happening in the following situation...

```
def cata[X](some: A => X, none: => X): X
```

Let me now call this method as follows:

```
def isDefined: Boolean = cata( _ => true, false)
```

I was wondering whether the type inferencer determines the type of `_ => true`to be `A => Boolean` or `Any => Boolean`. Due to the fact that `Function1` is *contra-variant* in its input parameter, both of the following compile just fine:

```
def isDefined: Boolean = cata( (_: A) => true, false)    //#1
def isDefined: Boolean = cata( (_: Any) => true, false)  //#2
```

So the question is, does the type inferencer come up with #1 or #2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this out:

```
trait MyOption[+A] {
   def cata[X](some: A => X, none: => X): X
   def isDefined: Boolean = cata( _ => true, false)
}
```

and compiled this with `scalac -Xprint:types`. This gave the following output:

```
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: myoption.scala
package  {
  abstract trait MyOption[A >: Nothing : Nothing  X, none: => X): X;
    def isDefined: Boolean = MyOption.this.cata[Boolean](((x$1: A) => true), false)
  }
}
```

So by the looks of it, the type inferencer came up with option #1.

Comment: Which version of `scalac` are you using?